Vue3 custom events are not (always) propagated
I checked out the code from Do custom events propagate up the component chain in Vue 3? were events did get propagated up. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fritznet/jqyta7cr/ (taken from linked question)
But when there is a emit call in the middle component Comp2 the propagation breaks. Why is this?
I tried explicitly setting inheritAttrs: true or adding the given events to the emits array. The only thing which works is emitting the event again (under a different name) Which somehow is counterintuitive and looks dirty to me. Especially since no .prevent modifier is used.
(catching the inner event (from Comp1) for debug reasons in Comp2 does not effect the result)
Here is an example which does NOT work:
https://jsfiddle.net/fritznet/kx8w2h90/19/


const Comp1 = {
  template: `
    <button @click="this.$emit('inner-event')">click me (inner)</button>
  `
}

const Comp2 = {
  components: {
    Comp1
  },
  emits: [
    "inner-event",
    "middle-event",
  ],
  template: `
  <div>
    <Comp1 @inner-event="console.log('at least it ended up here')"/>
    <button @click="this.$emit('middle-event')">other (middle)</button>
  </div>
  `,
  inheritAttrs: true 
}

const HelloVueApp = {
  components: {
    Comp2
  },
  methods: {
    log() {
      console.log("event handled APP");
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#hello-vue')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<div id="hello-vue" class="demo">
  <Comp2 @inner-event="log" @middle-event="log"/>
</div>



So my question is why both cases which are (in my eyes) the same do act differently? One time the get passed up and in the other case they are not bubbled up.

emit events do not bubble, by design (read the tip). You'll only fire log in App if you emit inner-event from <Comp2 />.

thanks that's it. I was reading the wrong docs page ( https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling ) still strange that the first fiddle works

@Fritz due argument fallback you can still assign an event handler directly to a nested element/component

@AlexanderNenashev you mean like @custom-event="this.$emit('inner-event')" and further chain this on?
